# Prevent deletion of some products

Tags: crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

Hello i want to disable delete or prevent them from deleting certain products in some module when user clicks delete button. Is there any experts who knows this ?
Thanks in advance any help would be appreciated.

found a sample code trying to put it together but i think there something more missing. sorry im pretty new with this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['action'])
    && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'DetailView'){

    $sql = 'update AOS_Products set deleted = 0 where id ="'.$bean->id.'"p';
    $result = $GLOBALS['db']->query($sql);
    $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result);

} else{
    SugarApplication::appendErrorMessage("Warning: this product shouldn't be deleted.");
}
```

here's the delete button i want to disable.
[image: p1]

also the inspect element of the delete button:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up what products id you want to protect before execute the query

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['action'])
    && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'DetailView'){

   $arrayId = array(1, 2, 3, 4); //ids to protect

   $delete = True; //boolean used for check if delete or not
   foreach ($arrayId as $id) {
         if($bean->id == $id) //check if id to delete is one of the protected id's
         {  //looking the code i guess "$bean->id" have the product id
          $delete = False;
          }
   }

    if($delete)
    {
      //if true, run the query for delete
      $sql = 'update AOS_Products set deleted = 0 where id ="'.$bean->id.'"p';
     $result = $GLOBALS['db']->query($sql);
     $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result);
    }
    else
    {
       SugarApplication::appendErrorMessage("Warning: this product shouldn't be deleted.");
    }



} else{
    //Any message related to the reason of no access the first if
}
```

Comment: thanks @P. Dev for taking your time to answer my question. Ive tried it but the product still got deleted but anyways i'll try to figure out wht anyways thank so much man you were a great teacher.

Comment: no problem, if you have more information or more part of the code you are using i can try to help you

Comment: This is also the ids i want to protect.
$arrayId = array('bab57581-ef23-e4c2-57f8-5bb2e5d979ed', '56074c00-2e78-94b2-72ab-5bb2e5be07e7', '62dbfff2-c084-1685-fa59-5b88aa2a7705');

Comment: I think a good idea is to use an if for decide when to make enable the delete button or not, that have to be added to the view/controller that is redirecting/rendering to the site you are showing. So in the given case that the view that is loading is for an protected product (not allow to be deleted)  the button is set to hidden and/or disable. I hope this help you

Comment: okay man atleast im not mental block in this problem thank you for giving and sharing your idea.

Comment: Best way is to remove delete button from both places ie  listview and detailView.

Comment: I found an extension to handle any such situation like this ie removing/hiding certain elements from anyview,  https://store.outrightcrm.com/product/suitecrm-global-hide-manager/

Answer (score 0):

In view.detail.php add below line

unset($this->dv->defs['templateMeta']['form']['buttons'][2]);